# MacBook chargers turns green, then red, and then stops charger

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power

I have been using a MacBook charger for about 6 months, and now I tried to use another one which I have used before with this MacBook.

Now, the battery is low enough that the MacBook can’t start, but only display the battery icon on the screen.

When connecting it to the power, the charger led turns green, then red (signaling that it is charging) and finally, turns off (after about 15 seconds).

I tried cooling down the MacBook and the charger, and after that I tried recharging. It did work for a longer time, but then the behavior explained above appeared again.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

---

The other charger does work. This charger stops working once the MacBook is started (or woke up from sleep).

Comment: How old is the Battery. What Mac model is it. What OSX? Did you try to do verified SMC reset ?

Comment: @Ruskes 3 years old, it’s pretty good still. It’s a MacBook Air 2015 (or 2016). macOS Mojave. Yes, I tried. No difference...

Comment: Thank you, It could be just dirty MagSafe connection. Could you publish the battery conditions from About this Mac. Your Mac should be able to run without battery, but it does not indicating bad charger, bad connection or failure in logic board.

Comment: @Ruskes no, it won’t power up... except displaying the battery icon indicating it should be connected to power

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one charger works, and another doesn’t, the non-working one is most probably broken and needs to be replaced.